# GROUP BY date not datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I am trying to write a query to count every date in my database as you can see here :

```
SELECT 
    [SubmitDateTime],
    COUNT(*)
FROM 
    [ParkingDB].[dbo].[Traffic] 
GROUP BY 
    submitdatetime
```

The result is :

[image]

I think SQL Server is grouping my date based on date+time and it's my problem, but in fact I need to group them based on date. I use this type of query :

```
SELECT 
    [SubmitDateTime],
    COUNT(*)
FROM 
    [ParkingDB].[dbo].[Traffic] 
GROUP BY
    CAST(myDateTime AS DATE)
```

But it doesn't work. I'm getting this error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Column
>   'ParkingDB.dbo.Traffic.SubmitDateTime' is invalid in the select list
>   because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>   GROUP BY clause.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work?

Comment: @FelixPamittan i get this error :Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Column 'ParkingDB.dbo.Traffic.SubmitDateTime' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: You have two working answers below. I suggest you marked either one as the answer so that this question will be resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to modify the columns in your `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT
    CAST([SubmitDateTime] AS DATE),
    COUNT(*)
FROM [ParkingDB].[dbo].[Traffic]
GROUP BY
    CAST([SubmitDateTime] AS DATE)
```

When using `GROUP BY` clause, all non-aggregated columns in the `SELECT` statement must appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: I think i am a little new in sqlserver ,because i write my queries with EF .

Answer (score 3):

Can you try the query below?

```
SELECT 
      CAST(myDateTime AS DATE) [SubmitDateTime],
      COUNT(*)
FROM [ParkingDB].[dbo].[Traffic]
GROUP BY 
      CAST(myDateTime AS DATE)
```